# Зачем в возвращаемом значении <T> если оно boolean или void?

Tags: java, generics, типы

Допустим в первом методе совпадает `<T>` как в принимаемых так и возвращаемых типах, но во второй метод просто ставит в ступор.

В чём смысл?

```
interface Collection<E> {
     public <T> boolean containsAll(Collection<T> c);
    public <T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c); 
}
```

Comment: А подумать/поэкспериментировать что вам мешает? Все ж на поверхности )

Comment: Если ставит, то как?

Answer (score 0):

В такой записи:

```
public <T> boolean containsAll(Collection<T> c);
```

`<T>` - это не часть возвращаемого типа функции, это индикатор того, что метод параметризирован типом. Метод возвращает просто `bool`, а вот принимает коллекцию объектов любого типа, именно об этом говорит .

Что качается того, почему во втором методе `<T extends E>`. Рассмотрим пример:

```
Collection<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Так так `Integer` наследуется от `Number`, то вы справедливо можете ожидать, что можно добавлять объекты типа `Integer` в коллекцию `Collection<Number>` используя `add`:

```
numbers.add(new Integer(1));
```

И такого же поведения мы ожидаем от `addAll`, т.е должно быть допустимо сделать:

```
Collection<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();

Collection<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

numbers.addAll(integers);
```

А для этого нельзя чтоб в `addAll` принимались только `Collection<E>` (т.е. в случае этого примера только `Collection<Number>`), нужно допускать любые коллекции с элементами типов унаследованных от `E`.

Тут важный момент, что хотя `Integer` является наследником от `Number`, `Collection<Integer>` не является наследником от `Collection<Number>`.

Comment: Здорово, спасибо что помогли!

Answer (score 0):

`<T>` не в возвращаемом значение, а перед ним. Просто такой синтаксис для определения обобщённых методов. И этот тип `Т` будет зависить от того что передали в метод. И обратите внимание что при объявление типа `Collection<E>` для параметра типа исполюзуется `E`.

В `containsAll` параметры `E` и `T` никак не связаны наследованием поэтому при вызове этого метода, например, на объекти типа Collection можно будет передать Collection. На любом объекте можно вызвать `equals`, так что такой вариант поведения подходит.

Метод `addAll` уже ограничивает типы аргументов, которые мы можем в него передать, т.к нам нужно, чтобы коллекция смогла поместить в себя объекты из переданной коллекции. При вызове этого метода на `Collection<Number>` подойдут аргументы `Collection<Number>`, `Collection<Integer>` или `Collection<Double>`. В этом случаи `E` будет `Number`, а `T` - `Number`, `Integer` или `Double`, и все типы этих объектов можно будет поместить в коллекцию `Collection<Number>`.

```
public class SO1418546 {

    interface Collection<E> {
        public <T> boolean containsAll(Collection<T> c);

        public <T extends E> void addAll(Collection<T> c);
    }

    static class TheCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
        @Override
        public <T> boolean containsAll(Collection<T> c) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends E> void addAll(Collection<T> c) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<Number> numberCollection = new TheCollection<>();

        //OK
        numberCollection.containsAll(new TheCollection<String>());
        numberCollection.containsAll(new TheCollection<Thread>());

        //compile error
        numberCollection.addAll(new TheCollection<String>());

        //OK
        numberCollection.addAll(new TheCollection<Integer>());
        numberCollection.addAll(new TheCollection<Number>());
        numberCollection.addAll(new TheCollection<Double>());

    }

}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь все ясно!